# Javascript/Jquery - fill array with missing entrys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to generate some raw-data for a chart and I'm facing a problem I can't solve.

I have an array with nested arrays that contains the data for x/y-axis

And it is generated from given answers to a question, now there are possibly answers that are not answered, so they do not show up in the data.

To make it more easy to understand:

```
questions.length = 5

generatedData = [[3,2],[1,3]]

wantToHaveData = [[0,0],[1,3],[2,0],[3,2],[4,0]]
```

so I need a way to insert all missing data in generated data to fulfill `questions.length`

If I iteratively go over the array and search for existing values I have a problem to difference between x-axis and y-axis e.g.:

```
for(var i; i < questions.length;i++){
   if( $.inArray( i, generatedData ) == -1) { // how to let this check only the first entry of nested array ? 
      generatedData.push([i,0]);
   }
```

I hope someone understands my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You can use the native [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

```
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length;i++){
    if( !generatedData.some(function(datapoint){ return datapoint[0] == i})) {
      generatedData.push([i,0]);
   }
}
/*generatedData = [[3, 2], [1, 3], [0, 0], [2, 0], [4, 0]]*/
```

**Solution 2:** However, I would prefer to construct an array of default values and then fill in the generated ones. This way the data points are returned in order and the performance should be better.

```
/* Construct array of default values. [[0,0], [1,0], ...[n,0]]*/
filledData = Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(function(elem, idx){return [idx, 0];});
for(var i = 0; i < generatedData.length; i++){
    filledData[generatedData[i][0]] = generatedData[i];
}
/*filledData = [[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 0], [3, 2], [4, 0]]*/
```

Comment: thank you ery much i will take your second one! works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can get generated **x** something like this

```
var generatedX = generatedData.map(function(point){return point[0]}); // [3,1]
```

and then use loop like this

```
for(var i=0; i < questions.length;i++){
    if( $.inArray( i, generatedX ) == -1) { 
        generatedData.push([i,0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
for(var i; i < questions.length;i++)
{
    if (typeof generatedData[i,0] !== 'undefined' && generatedData[i,0] !== null)
    {    
        generatedData.push([i,0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed the `jQuery` tag here is a native JS way of achieving the fill:

```
function fill(arr, size){
    var tmpArray = [];
    var indexes = arr.map(function(e,i){
        return {"i":e[0], "e":e};
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
        var selected = indexes.filter(function(e){
           return e.i == i;
        });
        if(selected.length){
            for(var x = 0; x < selected.length; x++){
                tmpArray.push(selected[x].e);
            }
        }else{
            tmpArray.push([i,0]);
        }
    }
    return tmpArray;
};
```